# Ignoring parentheticals in LawTeX citations

Tags: citing, legal-style

The `LawTeX` package ([here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/lawtex/)) includes `bluebook.sty` to automate legal citations.

In legal writing, the term "*Id.*" is used to repeat the immediately preceding citation.  But there's an exception (Bluebook Rule 4.1).  In the exception, *Id.* may still be used to refer to the "preceding" citation when a parenthetical citation intervenes.  In this text

> Here is sentence one.  *Tuten v. United States*, 460 U.S. 660, 663 (1983) (quoting *Ralston v. Robinson*, 454 U.S. 201,206 (1981)). Here is sentence two.  *Id.*

the *Id.* at the end ignores the parenthetical citation, which is *Ralston*, and refers instead to the preceding citation, which is *Tuten*.

**Question**

In `LawTeX`, can anyone see an automated way to recognize, and thus ignore the parenthetical, so as to get *Id.* to follow it?

**Example**

Say we're interested in printing the following text:

> Here is sentence one.  *Tuten v. United States*, 460 U.S. 660, 663 (1983). Here is sentence two.  *Id.*

Then we can write:

```
\providecommand{\documentclassflag}{}
\documentclass[12pt,\documentclassflag]{lawbrief} 
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{newcent,microtype,setspace,xcolor}
\usepackage[hyperindex=false,linkbordercolor=white,pdfborder={0 0 0}]{hyperref}

\citecase{Tuten v. United States, 460 U.S. 660 (1983)}
\citecase{Ralston v. Robinson, 454 U.S. 201 (1981)}

\begin{document}

Here's sentence one.  \pincite{Tuten}{663}.  
Here's sentence two.  \pincite{Tuten}{663}.

\end{document}
```

However, if we instead want to include a parenthetical and print

> Here is sentence one.  *Tuten v. United States*, 460 U.S. 660, 663 (1983) (quoting *Ralston v. Robinson*, 454 U.S. 201,206 (1981)). Here is sentence two.  *Id.*

then when using

```
\providecommand{\documentclassflag}{}
\documentclass[12pt,\documentclassflag]{lawbrief} 
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{newcent,microtype,setspace,xcolor}
\usepackage[hyperindex=false,linkbordercolor=white,pdfborder={0 0 0}]{hyperref}

\citecase{Tuten v. United States, 460 U.S. 660 (1983)}
\citecase{Ralston v. Robinson, 454 U.S. 201 (1981)}

\begin{document}

Here's sentence one.  \pincite{Tuten}{663} (quoting \pincite{Ralston}{206}).  
Here's sentence two.  \pincite{Tuten}{663}.

\end{document}
```

the `\pincite` for the second *Tuten* citation doesn't know the `\pincite` for the *Ralston* quotation is in a parenthetical and thus should be ignored.  It produces:

> Here is sentence one.  *Tuten v. United States*, 460 U.S. 660, 663 (1983). Here is sentence two.  *Tuten*, 460 U.S. at 663.

Comment: The Treachery of the Blue Books ...? Welcome!

Comment: Another example of the pointless inanity of common law citation schemes.... You at first say 'may' be ignored and then 'should'. If it is 'may', then I'd ignore it as it is much more logical and easier to implement programmatically. However, if it is indeed a 'should', then you're going to need to provide some guidance on where we can find the relevant packages.

Comment: @jon Thanks...I added a link for [LawTeX](https://sourceforge.net/projects/lawtex/), which includes the bluebook.sty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`bluebook.sty` is not easily hackable. The simplicity with which you can use `\citecase` means the internal macros are hellish because, as anyone familiar with [the horror that is the Bluebook](http://www.yalelawjournal.org/review/the-bluebook-blues) knows, the rules surrounding legal citations are overly prescriptive, pointlessly complicated, and serve mainly to ensure that only the *cognoscenti* will be able to decipher them (thereby completely destroying the point of citations in the first place).

This package does some very interesting things based on a very simple input via `\citecase`, though it is a rather idiosyncratic approach (I think).

So, anyway, what this means is: (1) it is impossible for `bluebook.sty` to be hacked in such a way that it automatically recognizes that a subsequent citation is embedded in a parenthetical and therefore should not foul up the *idem*-tracker without a complete overhaul of the package; and (2) we need to copy (and rename) a massive 132-line macro in order to comment out the two 'offending' lines. So bear with me.

Here's your example again, but note that I created a new command:

```
\newcommand{\parenpincite}[3][]{%
  \@startcitation\@ifnextchar.{\paren@bbsource{#2}{#3}{#1.}\@absorbperiod}{\paren@bbsource{#2}{#3}{#1}\xspace}}
```

It depends on a modified form of the command `\@bbsource`, which I have called `\paren@bbsource`. Ultimately, all we need to modify comes at lines 118 and 120 in the file below, where we comment out the lines:

```
\xdef\@bbLastSource{#1}
```

and

```
\protected@xdef\@bbLastPinPage{#2}
```

which are meant to store the value of the citation of the current use of `\pincite` and its pinpoint.

Putting it all together:

```
\providecommand{\documentclassflag}{}
\documentclass[12pt,\documentclassflag]{lawbrief}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{newcent,microtype,setspace,xcolor}
\usepackage[hyperindex=false,linkbordercolor=white,pdfborder={0 0 0}]{hyperref}

\makeatletter

\newcommand{\parenpincite}[3][]{%
\@startcitation\@ifnextchar.{\paren@bbsource{#2}{#3}{#1.}\@absorbperiod}{\paren@bbsource{#2}{#3}{#1}\xspace}}

%Inner command that performs the citations
% #1 is cite handle, #2 is pin or blank, #3 can include any of 'lsniIp'
\newcommand{\paren@bbsource}[3]
{%
    %Check that this source is defined
    \ifcsname #1@Type\endcsname%
        \relax%
    \else
        \errmessage{No source named #1 has been defined}
    \fi%
%
%
    %If user has passed "!", temporarily set autofootnote to do nothing
    %It is the case that all printing commands go through autofootnote
    \let\@@autofootnote=\@autofootnote%
    \IfSubStr{#3}{!}{\def\@autofootnote##1{}}{}%
%
    %If we are going to put this in an autofootnote, we want to take out the preceeding space
    %Additionally, add a period if a '.' has been set in the flags (which means that a period followed \cite), add a period.
    %This period, if it exists, will be stored in \@Period, which is used later on
    \def\@Period{}%
    \ifthenelse{\not \boolean{@bbLawReviewMode} \or \boolean{@bbInFootnote}}{}{\SafeUnskip}%
    \IfSubStr{#3}{.}{\def\@Period{.}}{}%
%
    \provideboolean{@forceLong}%
    \provideboolean{@forceShort}%
    \IfSubStr{#3}{l}{\setboolean{@forceLong}{true}}{\setboolean{@forceLong}{false}}%
    \IfSubStr{#3}{s}{\setboolean{@forceShort}{true}}{\setboolean{@forceShort}{false}}%
%
    %If ``n'' is provided in optional arg, force reporter and page number only (just for Cases)
    \IfSubStr{#3}{n}
    {%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{#2}{}}
            {\@autofootnote{\@bbSignal\@bbReporterOnlyCite{#1}}}
            {\@autofootnote{\@bbSignal\@bbReporterOnlyPinCite{#1}{#2}}}%
%
        %By definition, this last cite cannot be an "id", so reset the id counter
        \setcounter{@bbSequentialIds}{0}%
    }
    {%
        %Pull the volume number out of the pincite, or see if provided
        %The reason it is so messy looking is to deal with the fact that we do not want to fully expand the pincite,
        %  in case it contains formatting or other non-expandable control sequences
        \protected@edef\@fullpin{#2}%
        \expandarg%
        \StrBetween{\@fullpin}{vol. }{, }[\@vol]%
        \edef\@fullvol{vol. \@vol, }%
        \StrDel{\@fullpin}{\@fullvol}[\@pin]%
        \fullexpandarg%
%\show\@pin
%
        %If this authority has not been seen before, or we have not seen it in N notes, use complete form
        \ifthenelse{\boolean{#1@FirstUse} \or \boolean{@forceLong} \or%
            \( \boolean{@bbLawReviewMode} \and \( \equal{\SrcType{#1}}{Case} \or \equal{\SrcType{#1}}{Statute} \) \and
                \(  \( \not \boolean{@bbInFootnote} \and \numexpr\thefootnote-\LastNote{#1}+1\relax > \forcelongevery \) \or
                    \( \boolean{@bbInFootnote} \and \numexpr\thefootnote-\LastNote{#1}\relax > \forcelongevery \)
                \)
            \) }%
        {%
%\show\@pin
            \@autofootnote{\@bbSignal\@bbLongCite{#1}{\@pin}\@Period}%
            \setcounter{@bbSequentialIds}{0}%
            \ifthenelse{\boolean{#1@FirstUse}}{\XDef{#1@SupraNote}{\thefootnote}}{}%
        }
        {%
            %If this is the second occurance of this authority in a row, use Id
            \ifthenelse{\equal{\@bbLastSource}{#1} \and \not \boolean{@forceShort}%
                \and \value{@bbSequentialIds} < \maxsequentialids}
            {%
                %We only display the volume if it exists, and is DIFFERENT from the last; otw clear out
                \ifthenelse{\equal{\@vol}{\@bbLastVol}}{\edef\@vol{}}{}%
%
                %Choose either id/Id based on the capitalization flag
                \def\@Id{\ifthenelse{\boolean{@bbCapNextSource} \and \equal{\@vol}{}}{Id}{id}}%
%
                %The capitalization can be overridden based on the optional argument
                \IfSubStr{#3}{I}{\def\@Id{Id}}{}%
                \IfSubStr{#3}{i}{\def\@Id{id}}{}%
%
                %Choose either ``at'' or just a space based on the type of authority
                %\def\@At{\ifthenelse{\equal{\SrcType{#1}}{Statute}}{~}{~at~}}%
                %ALTERNATE: Use "at" iff the pin is numeric
                \def\@At{~}%
                \IfInteger{\@pin}{\def\@At{~at~}}{}%
%
                %If the exact page as well (or there is no pincite), just use id; otherwise use Id. with pin cite
                \ifthenelse{\equal{\@bbLastPinPage}{#2} \or \equal{}{#2} }
                    %{\@autofootnote{\@bbSignal\FillIn{}{\@vol}{ }\emph{\@Id}\@Period}} %I eliminated this because I found cases where there was no way to have a period after the Id.
                    {\@autofootnote{\@bbSignal\FillIn{}{\@vol}{ }\emph{\@Id\@Period}}}%
                    {\@autofootnote{\@bbSignal\FillIn{}{\@vol}{ }\emph{\@Id.}\@At\@pin\@Period}}%
                \stepcounter{@bbSequentialIds}%
            }%
            {%
                %If this is not the second-in-a-row occurence of this authority, use short form
                \@autofootnote{\@bbSignal\@bbShortCite{#1}{\@pin}\@Period}%
                \setcounter{@bbSequentialIds}{0}%
            }%
        }%
    }%
%
    %Indicate that this source has been used, so subsequent uses use short form
    %This gets into the internals of ifthen.sty, basically \setboolean calls the macro \<Boolean-Variable-Name><true-or-false>
    %By default, \setboolean is local to the group; we do the following to make the change global
    \globalsetboolean{#1@FirstUse}{false}%
%
    %Store the last used source, as well as pinpage and volume (if present) in that source, for determining Id
    %\xdef\@bbLastSource{#1}%  <--- NOTE: THIS LINE WAS COMMENTED OUT !!!
    %\xdef\@bbLastPinPage{\detokenize{#2}}%
    % \protected@xdef\@bbLastPinPage{#2}% <--- NOTE: THIS LINE WAS COMMENTED OUT !!!
    \ifthenelse{\not\equal{\@vol}{}}{\xdef\@bbLastVol{\@vol}}{}%
%
    %If in law review mode, store the footnote number, so we can force long cites after 5 footnotes
    \XDef{#1@LastNote}{\thefootnote}%
%
    %Record this use into the index, \pagenumber is the command that will be used to format
%PREVIOUSLY THIS WAS FULLNAME, WHY THE CHANGE
    %\index{\Call{#1@IndexType}}{\FullName{#1}@\@bbIndexCite{#1}{#2}|pagenumber}%
    %\index{\Call{#1@IndexType}}{\ShortName{#1}@\@bbIndexCite{#1}{#2}|pagenumber}%
    %\index{\Call{#1@IndexType}}{\ShortName{#1}@\@bbIndexCite{#1}{#2}}%
    \begingroup%
    \def\pin##1##2{}%
    \IfSubStr{#3}{*}{}{%
        \ifempty{\IndexType{#1}}{}{%
            \index{\IndexType{#1}}{\@bbIndexCite{#1}{#2}}%
        }%
    }%
    \endgroup%
%
    %Assume that we will capitalize the next Id, unless a signal word comes between
    \globalsetboolean{@bbCapNextSource}{true}%
    \def\@bbSignal{}%
%
    %Make sure to restore autofootnote (in case "!" was passed in, in which case it was redefined to do nothing)
    \let\@autofootnote=\@@autofootnote%
}
\makeatother

\citecase{Tuten v. United States, 460 U.S. 660 (1983)}
\citecase{Ralston v. Robinson, 454 U.S. 201 (1981)}

\begin{document}

Here's sentence one.  \pincite{Tuten}{663} (quoting \parenpincite{Ralston}{206}).
Here's sentence two.  \pincite{Tuten}{663}. 

Here's \pincite{Ralston}{206} to reset the tracker. Here's sentence one again:  \pincite{Tuten}{663} (quoting \parenpincite{Ralston}{206}).  
Here's sentence two, showing the \verb|Id.| plus the unique pinpoint: \pincite{Tuten}{664}.

\end{document}
```

[image: LawTeX picture]

**Disclaimer:** I do not own a copy of the *Bluebook* so I cannot verify the accuracy of the above citations. (I *am* stuck with the tyranny of the *McGill Guide*, however, so I can relate and commiserate....)

Comment: Great solution; we can all only hope for a world with liberalized citations...